# Open new window when already logged with watir

Tags: ruby, watir

Is there a way to open a new window or tab when already logged in a site, and open it as a logged user?
When I try to open it with a new browser window it opens it as a guest user.

My code structure simplified looks like this right now:

```
b.goto url
Login(b)
link = b."getlink"
new_b.goto link
```

I want new_b to open as logged.

Comment: Where are you already logged in? Is it in another browser window opened by Watir or one you've manually opened?

Comment: Another watir window.

Comment: @JustinKo I solved using (:shift) after clicking the link. But now I have a problem managing the windows since I'm running parallel processes that use the same watir instance. I guess they are fighting each others to get the window focus. Is there some reference to manage this kind of situation with watir?

Comment: Usually we'd expect each process to have its own Watir instance. Is there a reason each process couldn't be given their own Watir instance? Maybe it would help to explain overall what you are trying to do.